# Magento 2.X: Show notification on product added to the cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to show notification when i add product in cart right now when i add less then the products in the stock then i can see product added to cart but if i add more then the quantity in the stock then i am not seeing any alert or something , how can i do that ?

I have also tried store->configuration->catalog and inventory as well but unable to find out some solution . I have tried backorder option but it is not working as well

Answer (score -2):

Please go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options.
Display Out of Stock Products: Choose Yes to enable displaying out of stock products in the frontend.

Let me know if this helps